# How were artificial boulders and rocky outcroppings & edifices constructed for the sets of the original Star Trek episodes?

Tags: star-trek-tos, props, design

As a kid getting X-rayed sitting in front of an early model color television set, I was enthralled by the rocky planets that the crew of the USS Enterprise visited.

As an adult I'm still coming to terms with the idea that these were sets and props, and those giant boulders and (some of) the rocky outcroppings were constructed from (likely) cheap and light weight materials of some sort.

**Question:** How were artificial boulders and rocky outcroppings & edifices constructed for the sets of the original Star Trek episodes?

---

[image: Star Trek Shuttlecraft Galileo]

Source: [Shuttlecraft Galileo](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Galileo_(2267))

Answer (score 5):

This is partial atm:

This only references one or two episodes, so cannot speak for all of the sets during the series construction and run, however, some of this is interesting:

[image]

> Ladder to the Stars: Talos IV Surface Set Construction with Aluminum Foil
> This shot, digitized from a reference film owned by Matt Jefferies, shows the construction of the set used for the filming of the original 1964 pilot "The Cage." Visible are the rock outcropping and elevator components, a large piece of **aluminum foil for surface treatment**, the rocks which are being hoisted and put in place, and a normal wooden step ladder, ten feet or so in height by the looks of it.
>
> This set, while filmed beginning in November 1964, was being designed and constructed in August through October 1964, so 50 years ago now. Also visible in this shot is the green tinged cyclorama background, the hue chosen to give a more alien feel to the planet surface where the illusion of the Columbia crash survivors and Vina (and visiting Talosians) would encounter the crew of the Enterprise as captained by Christopher Pike. But you know all that .....

> It is known that the **rocks** were constructed by essentially **layering a plaster foam material onto foil and then painting it**. Here swaths of the aluminum foil can be seen that have not been coated yet.

All from this gorgeous gallery:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/birdofthegalaxy/page1

On second thoughts, these seem widely available bts stills from the filming of The Cage

Comment: This is great! I am glad I'm seeing it now, and not back in the 1970's when I was watching Star Trek reruns after school.

Answer (score 4):

The boulders were generally [spraypainted foam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VjJp_yhoVs). I suspect the rock faces were made of the same material. Trying to find a quote for it... [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20221112010431/https://www.yourprops.com/Enterprise-Rock-original-movie-prop-Star-Trek-Enterprise-TV-2001-YP23465.html) are two pieces being sold online. I've also seen references to them being made out of paper mache such as [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/startrek/comments/lxae74/st_tos_set_design_question/).

And, of course, [sometimes the rocks were real](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vasquez_Rocks).

Comment: But are these solid foam, or was there perhaps a wooden framework and chicken wire to support a skin of foam? I'm asking how they were constructed, not just what they were made of. Constructing those huge textured walls must have required some fabric or undulating mesh as well, perhaps plaster and cloth?

Comment: To a geologist, the foam boulders never look real. The overall forms are generally too spherical and the surfaces look draped over supports. In motion, they bounce too lightly and have too little effect on the soil and vegetation they hit. And usually there is no attempt at stratification. However, as FuzzyBoots points out, sometimes the rocks are real.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron yes I think I'm seeing "draped" in the back wall of the image in the question for example. My question does only ask about the "*artificial* boulders and rocky outcroppings & edifices" to avoid the "some were real" aspect.

Comment: The "pieces being sold online" are from Enterprise, not the original series. The reddit quote is unsourced. The video is utterly generic. This is a bad answer. No sourcing to TOS.

Comment: Yeah, i thought i had something from *Memories*, but no dice. Shatner doesn't seem to have mentioned the rocks after all.